# Why Is My Eclipse Java Program Not Running - Error Message: "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, eclipse, error-messaging

I am working on a Java project for a Computer Science class. For this class, I downloaded a zip file and imported it into Eclipse to then start working on it. Before I could even start writing code I had error messages which had never happened before when importing zip files and opening them up.

The first error message I came across was: "Linkage Error occurred while loading the main class", along with other side errors like, "Must define an explicit constructor".

I attempted to do some research and the only thing I could find was setting my JDK settings back to an earlier version. I went in and changed my compiler from JDK 15 to JDK 11 and attempted to run the code once again. Now instead of Linkage Error, it gives the error message which can be seen in the screenshot provided below:

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilN5M.jpg)

Does anyone know why this might be happening or have any suggestions/solutions? Let me know if any other information is needed. I will gladly provide it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try to resolve the issues:

Check the class path: Make sure that the class path is correctly set and that all required libraries and packages are included.

Clean the project: In Eclipse, go to "Project" -> "Clean" and select the project. This will delete all compiled files and rebuild the project.

Check the Java version: Make sure that you are using the correct Java version for your project. If the project was developed using a different version of Java, you may need to change your Java version to match.

Check the class name: Make sure that the class name in the Java file matches the name of the main class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The main class couldn't be found because it couldn't be compiled, and it couldn't be compiled because your project is missing a build path entry to a valid JRE. That's why String is also underlined--it is not found because it's expected to be provided from a Java runtime.

Double-check that the **Installed JREs** preference page has a valid Java 11 runtime defined. Eclipse uses Java to run itself, but you still have to tell it which JREs you want it to offer to compile your own projects against. Once a JRE is configured, open up the **Properties** dialog for your project and go to the **Java Build Path** property page. On its **Libraries** tab, click on **Classpath** and then the **Add Library...** button. Select JRE System Library from the list you're shown and then pick one to use. Choosing by **Execution environment** (think of it as the intended Java SE version number at *runtime*) is preferred.

[image: Adding a Library]
[image: Picking a JRE by Execution environment]